# Copy entire content from a folder to another in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, copy-paste

I'm trying every single code to copy all things inside a folder to another but i can't do it! I'm trying to use the code in my terminal emulator in my android device because i need that code in my application. This is the last code i use that doesn't work:

```
#!/bash/sh
srcdir="/data/app"
dstdir="/sdcard/prova1"

for f in ${srcdir}/*.apk
do
    cp $f $dstdir $dstfile
done
```

and the terminal says:

```
: not found
' unespectedsyntax error: 'do
```

can anyone help me? These are the possibility that could be good:

1) Copy all files in the /data/app folder to /sdcard/prova1

2) Copy directly the folder app in prova1

3) Use a java code that do one of these two things..

I have root so i can do this operation.

Comment: yes this is my goal.. i have wrong.. the only two var are the first two on top of script

Comment: what is strange is that if i try with a single file works:`cp /data/app/com.ab.application.apk /sdcard/prova1` but for all app not.

Answer (score 17):

None of these answers worked for me for recursive copy. Found this in a script in one of my libraries and thought I'd share it (with a subfolder example for both the source and destination, which is what I needed):

```
SOURCE="/my/folder"
DESTINATION="/my/destination"

cp -r "$SOURCE/subdir/"* "$DESTINATION/another_sub/"
```

With this, every subfolder and every file was copied.

I don't know why but **the asterisk outside the quotes** in the source did the magic for me (using bash 4.3.11 here)

Comment: It's because wildcards are not interpreted inside a quoted text.

Comment: Oh, Dang it I had the * inside the "". It makes sense why it goes outside, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

how about this, where `src` and `dest` are directories:

```
cp -r src dest
```

Answer (score 1):

Your file contains carriage returns, which is why you're getting these trashed error messages. Use `tr -d '\r' <yourscript >fixedscript` to get rid of them.

As for your script, the correct way to do it is

```
#!/bin/sh
cp /data/app/*.apk /sdcard/prova1
```

While the smallest fix to make your version work is

```
#!/bin/sh
srcdir="/data/app"
dstdir="/sdcard/prova1"

for f in ${srcdir}/*.apk
do
    cp $f $dstdir
done
```

Comment: One additional step is needed: the files need to be copied to `$dstdir/app`, or more generally `$dstdir/$(base name $srcdir)`, I think.

Comment: This one `cp /data/app/*.apk /sdcard/prova1` would be the best way for me but doesn't work..

Comment: @David_D Why not? are you trying to copy recursively, e.g. `/data/app/foo/bar/baz.apk` as well?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complex method to copy an entire source tree:

```
cd $srcdir && tar cf - . | ( cd $dstdir && tar xf - )
```

This tars the contents of the src directory to stdout, then pipes that to a subshell where you change to the dst dir and untar from stdin.

Comment: so this copy the entire folder to another?

Answer (score 0):

I think using rsync resolves your issue. Try something like this:
 rsync -avz source_path dest_path

Answer (score 0):

Just try out below code.  copy and paste that code in a text editor and save them as  **your_file_name.sh**

Then try to run on terminal   **sh ./your_file_name.sh**

```
cd "/data/app"

dstdir="/sdcard/prova1"


for f in *.apk

do

   cp -v "$f" ${dstdir} "${f%.apk}".apk

done

echo " "

echo "File copied successfully !!"
```

This will copy your file from source directory to your destination folder or directory.